# When Should I Care About REST?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, routes

When working on a personal project (a sports website) that I'm building in `php` with `Codeigniter` , would I gain anything from setting my application as `RESTful` ? I don't care about `APIs` (I'm the only one that's going to work on this project) . And even if I one day do care about making an `API` to the public , I don't see why I wouldn't be able to do it with Codeigniter`'s default`behaviour`.
Right now the routing is done like so

```
**base_domain/controller/controller_metho**d (as usual in CI)
```

Which seems just fine to me .

What or when will REST routing help me ?

Comment: If you are using client side javascript to make updates to server models, REST can be a good approach. It makes your code more simple and coherent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only one using the code of your site you don't need REST. REST is mostly used when you want to allow clients (other websites or smartphones) to access data and maybe update or insert data into your database. That's when you would create API. It gives you full control to deliver data to clients, without giving them any snippet of your code or your database structure. Furthermore you can secure your code and data by implementing either PrivateKey/ PublicKey or username/password authentication.

You don't have to start implementing REST before you start building your site. You can always add REST service later when you are ready.

Take a look at this RESTful class by Phil Sturgeon made for Codeigniter 2

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

And here is tutorial for the same thing

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/